# Dropup in TailwindCSS / AlpineJS

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css, alpine.js

Does anyone know how to build a 'dropup' in TailwindCSS /AlpineJS? I know how to build a dropdown but can't manage to make a dropup.

My dropdown:

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />

      <div class="flex-shrink-0 flex border-t border-gray-200 p-4">
        <a href="#" class="flex-shrink-0 group block">
          <div class="flex items-center">
            <div @click.away="open = false" class="relative" x-data="{ open: false }">
                  <div>
                    <button @click="open = !open" class="max-w-xs flex items-center text-sm rounded-full text-white focus:outline-none focus:shadow-solid transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                      <img class="inline-block h-8 w-8 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=2&amp;w=256&amp;h=256&amp;q=80" alt="">
            <div class="ml-3">
              <p class="text-sm leading-5 font-medium text-gray-700 group-hover:text-gray-900">
                John Doe
              </p>
              <p class="text-xs text-left leading-4 font-medium text-gray-500 group-hover:text-gray-700 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                View profile
              </p>
            </div>                      
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div x-show="open" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-100" x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95" x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100" x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75" x-transition:leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100" x-transition:leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95" class="origin-top-right absolute left-0 mt-2 -mr-1 w-48 rounded-md shadow-lg">
                    <div class="py-1 rounded-md bg-white shadow-xs relative">
                      <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 transition ease-in-out duration-150">Your Profile</a>
                      <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 transition ease-in-out duration-150">Settings</a>
                      <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 transition ease-in-out duration-150">Sign out</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s4m6vea7/

Thanks!

Comment: Just to avoid any confusion, could you define what you mean by "dropup", perhaps with an illustration or something.

Comment: Thanks for you reaction! Normally a dropdown is going down. I want the opposite: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9u7Jk9dE8do/maxresdefault.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### With minimal changes

I do know how to build this. Building the drop up is easy. Spacing it out evenly is more difficult. In [this code pen](https://jsfiddle.net/jacobshenning/docqexgj/6/), I took your example and made it work without changing very much. I added the `bottom-0` class to the dropdown. I also added an `mb-12` class to it would sit above the button. This isn't a super dynamic fix though, you'll have to add margins to the bottom of every element you use it on.

#### A solid solution

I changed [this code pen](https://jsfiddle.net/jacobshenning/docqexgj/8/) to have a wrapper around the dropup. By wrapping the dropup I was able to get the `bottom-0` class to start at the top of the dropdown. Any margin added will be consistent regardless of the dropup height.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you Jacob for you help. Really appreciate it!